# Error while extracting file from RPM (rpm2cpio)

Tags: linux, rpm, rhel

I'm using the following command to extract a single file from RPM package.

```
 pm2cpio <RPM_NAME> | cpio -ivdm <FILE_NAME>
```

It works fine for me, but on one system (RHEL5.9), I'm getting this error:

```
 cpio: premature end of file
```

I've googled it but couldn't find any appropriate answer and solution.
Can someone encountered this issue and can help?

Comment: Maybe your rpm package is corrupted. Usage tools such as `sha256sum` compute the checksums of these rpm packages and make sure they are the same.

Comment: How it will help me this usage tool? in addition, what can be corrupted in the rpm package? isn't it something with the cpio?

Comment: First of all, you should make sure you are use the **exactly** same rpm package in these two systems.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is mentioned in the Redhat Bugzilla item [rpm2cpio fails on rhel-6 rpms](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=602423#c7) and includes a quick fix similar to the following, which requires that the xz package is installed:

```
rpm2cpio foo.rpm | xzcat | cpio -idmv
```

Comment: Works for me whilst installed Centos' RPM on Windriver Linux.

Answer (score 1):

If the RPM is from Fedora 12 or later, it probably uses [a different compression](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Features/XZRpmPayloads). You need at least RPM v4.6 to read those RPMs, and RHEL5 only ships with [4.4](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2013-0061.html).

I'm assuming your other system is Fedora 10 or above, or some other distro with RPM v4.6 or above.