# Extract RPM package cpio

Tags: linux, extract, rpm, cpio

i am getting and error while extract rpm package which is below. I run this command many times before but this time it shows me an error. I try to run this command on Oracle Linux 7. What should i do ?

```
rpm2cpio couchbase-server-enterprise-6.5.0-oel7.x86_64.rpm | cpio --extract --make-directories --no-absolute-filenames

cpio: premature end of file
```

Comment: Try to download rpm file again

Comment: yes, i did but nothing change

Comment: Try first just to convert the file to cpio archive: `rpm2cpio couchbase-server-enterprise-6.5.0-oel7.x86_64.rpm >couchbase.cpio`, then check the list of files `cpio -t <couchbase.cpio`

Comment: Script : Unpack rpm-package to a directory with package name : unPack_rpm.sh (534 B) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1q3d9QqrRhEThYByPDgWEaoxHnqWFWqfE/view?usp=sharing ... The classic unpack command is : `rpm2cpio [package.rpm] | cpio -idmv`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while extracting file from RPM (rpm2cpio)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21875589/error-while-extracting-file-from-rpm-rpm2cpio)

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco i check that post but didnt change anything. still same

Comment: @RomeoNinov i run cpio -t <couchbase.cpio that command , then it says cpio: premature end of archive . i think some of files are not moving when i send them to my vmware machine

Answer (score 1):

Ok. I solved it. when transfer the rpm file, some of the files can be missing. be sure your rpm file is not corrupt. try another way to tranfer the file. Thanks.